# GitLab CI/CD - setup for LAMP project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, lamp, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a regular LAMP project and we recently to moved to Gitlab (instead of Github).

Previously we have been using Jenkins for deployment, now I am planning to migrate it to *Gitlab CI/CD*.

We have *servers A and B* (with Loadbalancer) for *development* version and *servers C and D* (likewise, with LB) for *production* environment.

Since it's a LAMP project, the deploy is as simple as that:
- latest changes are pulled from repo;
- all changed files are rsynced into public web folder;
- some utilities like *composer* and *npm* are run.

Basically I need to deploy changes to two development VPS and two production ones.

Do I have to install and start runner on each of them? Or is there a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches possible (I'm assuming your are running on unix) :

- Simply create a new server and [install](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) the gitlab-runner on it and register it. Install the dependencies on the server itself.
- If you are confident with docker, I suggest you to install it as [Docker service](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html). For the dependencies, create a docker image adding the utilies and refers the container image in the `config.toml` [advanced configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) with the `--image` flag. This will trigger a container based on your image for every build.
- If you know Kubernetes, use [kubernetes executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerskubernetes-section) and build directly on the cluster. You still need to build your own image with dependencies and refers it in the runner configuration with `--kubernetes-image`

For the deployment, just copy the files on your target servers after the build using tools like `scp` or `rsync`. Better (if your LAMP project is dockerized) : build a docker image, push it on a registry and pull it on your server. Even better : deploy all the containers in a orchestrator like Kubernetes.